# Why to use nested class in builder design pattern, why can't use setters to build the object in the same class

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, static, nested

I've visited few sites regarding java builder design pattern. Most of them are showing, to build the class we need to add static nested class by calling the respective setters, then triggering object creation. But query is, why can't we use those setters in the same class without the static nested class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to following reasons:

a. It might happen that you exposed your instance and you are still in middle of object creation via setter method.

b. You would like to make your outer instance immutable.

c. You are separating construction of object with its representation.

d. You would need more control over its construction then representation.

Comment: You are talking about during multiple threads accessing that code?

Comment: @user1702457 immutability is a useful property for multithreading, but more generally it just allows you to reason about the state of objects - which allows you to know that single-threaded code works in a particular way also.